# DHCP/DNS and multiple VLANs

Tags: domain-name-system, active-directory, dhcp

I'm having an issue regarding DNS/DHCP and multiple VLANs, the following network scheme is in-place:

The DNS Server is running along the AD Server on one VM (Windows Server 2008R2 version) and the DHCP is running on other VM (Windows Server 2012R2) and has 2 scopes, one for the VLAN 1 and other for the VLAN 2. One VLAN is for Cable Network and other Wireless Network.

Everything works fine, computers switch between cable and wireless they get the correct IP from DHCP to their respective VLAN.

The problem resides on the DNS part, when you try to ping the computer name after a VLAN/Scope change the DNS points tho the old one. Even if you clean cache.

What could be the main reasons for this?

Thanks

Comment: You need to enable DNS scavenging on your DNS server and your DNS zone and you need to make sure that the scavenging settings are appropriate to your DHCP lease time.